# iphone: Making pointer to UITableViewCell crashing app?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView with about 20 cells.  I wanted to make a pointer to three of those cells, so I set up a property for those, then pointed them to those cells:

```
if ([item.title isEqualToString:@"Test1"]) {
  test1 = cell;
} else if ([item.title isEqualToString:@"test2"]) {
  test2 = cell;
}
```

If I scroll up and down in my table view over and over it will crash my app.  But, removing this pointer code fixes the crashing issue.

Why would making a pointer to a cell make my app crash?

**Edit:**

```
if ([item.title isEqualToString:@"Test1"]) {
        self.test1 = cell;
} else if ([item.title isEqualToString:@"test2"]) {
        self.test2 = cell;
}
```

I just updated my code to use self. and it seems to fix the crashing issue. Could this be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use self. if you want to call the property, if no, you are just calling your instance variable.

And with property, I think that it already supports you with `(retain)` then you really owns the test1 and test2 and later on, you can call method on them

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate you verifying this.